# SwiftUI state management

Tags: swiftui, binding, state, observableobject, property-wrapper-published

I have encountered an architectural problem with SwiftUI state.

Consider an architecture with a uni-directional data flow.

```
class Store: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var state: AppState = AppState(initialValue: 0)

    func fetchInitialValue() async {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        state = AppState(initialValue: 5)
    }
}

struct AppState {
    let initialValue: Int
}
```

We have an `ObservableObject` - `Store`, which has a `@Published` variable `State`, which can only be updated internally. This state contains an initial value for some view, which can be updated after the view initially presented (e.g. it can be fetched from some remote system).

Now, this `initialValue` should be only an initial value for that view, it shouldn't be a two-way binding, but whenever it is updated, the view should update.

Here is an example view hierarchy using this state. Note, that the view can change the value on its own, which should not affect the `initialValue`.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = Store()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Initial value is \(store.state.initialValue)")

            SubView(initialValue: store.state.initialValue)
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await store.fetchInitialValue()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @State var currentValue: Int

    init(initialValue: Int) {
        currentValue = initialValue
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper(value: $currentValue) {
                Text("Current value is \(currentValue)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `SubView` will not update on the state update, because none of its subviews depend on the `initialValue`.

Any ideas how to force `SubView` to recreate on the state change?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@ObservedObject` where you own the object. Use `@StateObject`

Comment: Make it depend on the store somehow. For example using the `id` modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View re-renders on the state change. Passing a value type like the `initialValue` which is an integer will not update it dependant to the store. So make it change the state. For example using the `id` modifier:

```
SubView(initialValue: store.state.initialValue)
    .id(store.state.initialValue)
```

or passing the store itself:

```
SubView(store: store)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Didn't know about `id` modifier. That fixes the issue, although not the best looking code :-D

Answer (score 0):

You need an action to set the initial state to the model value.  You could do it in onAppear after your fetch.

FYI for async await in SwiftUI it's .task or .task(id:) not Task{}